# Convert everything in a dictionary to lower case, then filter on it?

Tags: python-3.x, lowercase, ordereddictionary

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import os

directory = os.listdir(r"C:\...")

x = []
num = 0

for i in directory:
    x.append(pd.read_fwf("C:\\..." + i))
    x[num] = x[num].to_string()
```

So, once I have a dictionary x = [ ] populated by the read_fwf for each file in my directory:

- I want to know how to make it so every single character is lowercase. I am having trouble understanding the syntax and how it is applied to a dictionary.
- I want to define a filter that I can use to count for a list of words in this newly defined dictionary, e.g.,

list = [bus, car, train, aeroplane, tram, ...]

**Edit: Quick unrelated question:**

Is pd_read_fwf the best way to read .txt files? If not, what else could I use?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

**Edit 2: Sample data and output that I want:**

Sample:

> The Horncastle boar's head is an early seventh-century Anglo-Saxon
>   ornament depicting a boar that probably was once part of the crest of
>   a helmet. It was discovered in 2002 by a metal detectorist searching
>   in the town of Horncastle, Lincolnshire. It was reported as found
>   treasure and acquired for £15,000 by the City and County Museum, where
>   it is on permanent display.

Required output - changes everything in uppercase to lowercase:

> the horncastle boar's head is an early seventh-century anglo-saxon
>   ornament depicting a boar that probably was once part of the crest of
>   a helmet. it was discovered in 2002 by a metal detectorist searching
>   in the town of horncastle, lincolnshire. it was reported as found
>   treasure and acquired for £15,000 by the city and county museum, where
>   it is on permanent display.

Comment: `x` is an array. Also, since you are never changing `num`, the last operation will be repeated on the same index (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use pandas or dictionaries at all. Just use Python's built-in `open()` function:

```py
# Open a file in read mode with a context manager
with open(r'C:\path\to\you\file.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Read the file into a string
    text = file.read()
    # Use the string's lower() method to make everything lowercase
    text = text.lower()
    print(text)

    # Split text by whitespace into list of words
    word_list = text.split()
    # Get the number of elements in the list (the word count)
    word_count = len(word_list)
    print(word_count)
```

If you want, you can do it in the reverse order:

```py
# Open a file in read mode with a context manager
with open(r'C:\path\to\you\file.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Read the file into a string
    text = file.read()
    # Split text by whitespace into list of words
    word_list = text.split()
    # Use list comprehension to create a new list with the lower() method applied to each word.
    lowercase_word_list = [word.lower() for word in word_list]
    print(word_list)
```

Using a context manager for this is good since it automatically closes the file for you as soon as it goes out of scope (de-tabbed from `with` statement block). Otherwise you would have to use `file.open()` and `file.read()`.

I think there are some other benefits to using context managers, but someone please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is dictionary comprehension:

```py
# Python 3
new_dict = {key: val.lower() for key, val in old_dict.items()}

# Python 2
new_dict = {key: val.lower() for key, val in old_dict.iteritems()}
```

`items()`/`iteritems()` gives you a list of tuples of the `(keys, values)` represented in the dictionary (e.g. `[('somekey', 'SomeValue'), ('somekey2', 'SomeValue2')]`)

The comprehension iterates over each of these pairs, creating a new dictionary in the process. In the `key: val.lower()` section, you can do whatever manipulation you want to create the new dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just wanted to clarify two things: Firstly, are you saying that instead of using an array, where i defined x = [], I should define x as a dictionary? Secondly, how would I integrate that into my loop? I don't see any indexes in the code you posted, so I'm a little confused

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. So is the only thing you are trying to do is to read and manipulate something in a text file? Also, could you post a sample of the format of the file (substitute any sensitive data if need be)? That would help me find a good solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I've put a sample of the data, and required output. What I'm trying to do is - the list in my array has a mixture of upper-case and lower-case values. This needs to be all lower-case

Comment: Just posted a new answer based on what you wanted